# Vue3 useFetch with composable

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt3, composable

I am quite new to vue3 and have some difficulty using useAsyncData and composable together in nuxt3.
I have search Form and list table something like this

```
<v-form>
 <v-row>
  <v-col cols="12" md="4">
    <v-text-field label="name" hide-details clearable v-model="name></v-text-field>
  </v-col>
 </v-row>
 <v-btn @click="searchPage()">search</v-btn>
</v-form>

<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="items" :loading="pending"  disable-pagination>
  <template v-slot:item="{ item, index }">
    <tr>
      <td>{{ item.raw.name}}</td>
      <td><NuxtLink to="/items/detail/">{{ item.raw.id }}</NuxtLink></td>
    </tr>
  </template>

  <template v-slot:bottom>
    <div class="text-center pt-2">
      <v-pagination v-model="page" :length="pageCount" color="blue darken-4"></v-pagination>
    </div>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

composable/useFetchData.ts

```
export function useFetchData() {
 const page = ref(1);
  const state = reactive({
    items: [],
    total: 0,
  });

  const getData = async (params: object) => {
    const {data: response,pending,error,refresh,} = await useAsyncData(
      "test",
      () =>
        $fetch('https://api.roastandbrew.coffee/api/v1/cafes', {
          method: "GET",
          params: params,
        }),
      {
        watch: [page.value],
      }
    );
    state.items = response.value.data;
  };

return {
    getData,
    page
    ...toRefs(state),
  };
}
```

And script setup

```
<script setup lang="ts">
let { items, page, total, getData } =useFetchData()
getData({});

const searchPage = function() {
  getData({('name' : name});
}
</script>
```

But it does not called getData() again on page change despite of watching page value and bind into v-model .
Also get parameters(:form values) are not displaying in url. I know i'm doing something wrong and can't figure out how to. It will be a really help if someone can guide me on this

Comment: does await useFetchData() works?